# Override `drop` for a custom sequence

Tags: clojure, overriding

In short: in Clojure, is there a way to redefine a function from the standard sequence API (which is not defined on any interface like ISeq, IndexedSeq, etc) on a custom sequence type I wrote?

---

### 1. Huge data files

I have big files in the following format:

- A long (8 bytes) containing the number `n` of entries
- `n` entries, each one being composed of 3 longs (ie, 24 bytes)

### 2. Custom sequence

I want to have a sequence on these entries. Since I cannot usually hold all the data in memory at once, and I want *fast* sequential access on it, I wrote a class similar to the following:

```
(deftype DataSeq [id
                  ^long cnt
                  ^long i
                  cached-seq]
  clojure.lang.IndexedSeq

  (index [_]     i)
  (count [_]     (- cnt i))
  (seq   [this]  this)
  (first [_]     (first cached-seq))
  (more  [this]  (if-let [s (next this)] s '()))

  (next [_] (if (not= (inc i) cnt)
              (if (next cached-seq)
                (DataSeq. id cnt (inc i) (next cached-seq))
                (DataSeq. id cnt (inc i)
                          (with-open [f (open-data-file id)]
                             ; open a memory mapped byte array on the file
                             ; seek to the exact position to begin reading
                             ; decide on an optimal amount of data to read
                             ; eagerly read and return that amount of data
                          ))))))
```

The main idea is to read ahead a bunch of entries in a list and then consume from that list. Whenever the cache is completely consumed, if there are remaining entries, they are read from the file in a new cache list. Simple as that.

To create an instance of such a sequence, I use a very simple function like:

```
(defn ^DataSeq load-data [id]
  (next (DataSeq. id (count-entries id) -1 [])))
; count-entries is a trivial "open file and read a long" memoized
```

As you can see, the format of the data allowed me to implement `count` in very simply and efficiently.

### 3. `drop` could be O(1)

In the same spirit, **I'd like to reimplement `drop`**. The format of these data files allows me to reimplement `drop` in O(1) (instead of the standard O(n)), as follows:

- if dropping less then the remaining cached items, just drop the same amount from the cache and done;
- if dropping more than `cnt`, then just return the empty list.
- otherwise, just figure out the position in the data file, jump right into that position, and read data from there.

My difficulty is that `drop` is not implemented in the same way as `count`, `first`, `seq`, etc. The latter functions call a similarly named static method in `RT` which, in turn, calls my implementation above, while the former, `drop`, does not check if the instance of the sequence it is being called on provides a custom implementation.

Obviously, I could provide a function named anything but `drop` that does exactly what I want, but that would force other people (including my future self) to remember to use it instead of `drop` every single time, which sucks.

#### So, the question is: **is it possible to override the default behaviour of `drop`?**

### 4. A workaround (I dislike)

While writing this question, I've just figured out a possible workaround: make the reading even lazier. The custom sequence would just keep an index and postpone the reading operation, that would happen only when `first` was called. The problem is that I'd need some mutable state: the first call to `first` would cause some data to be read into a cache, all the subsequent calls would return data from this cache. There would be a similar logic on `next`: if there's a cache, just `next` it; otherwise, don't bother populating it -- it will be done when `first` is called again.

This would avoid unnecessary disk reads. However, this is still less than optimal -- it is still O(n), and it could easily be O(1).

Anyways, I don't like this workaround, and my question is still open. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, after some discussion with @tomoj on #clojure, it seems that it is not currently possible to override the behaviour of `drop` in clojure.core. The solution would be to modify core.clj to make drop call RT.drop, that would check if the coll implements IDrop (ie, an interface that defines `drop(n)`) and call drop(n) if it does, otherwise fallback to the standard "iterate and discard" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, I implemented the workaround I described above. It works by deferring the reading to the first call to `(first)`, which will store the data on a local, mutable cache.

Note that **this version uses `unsynchronized-mutable`** (to avoid volatile-reads on every call to `first`, `next` and `more` and a volatile-write on the first call to `first`). In other words: **DON'T SHARE AMONG THREADS**. To make it thread-safe, use `volatile-mutable` instead (which causes a small performance penalty). It could still cause multiple reads of the same data by different threads. To avoid that, change back to `unsynchronized-mutable` and be sure to use `(locking this ...)` when reading from or writing to the field `cache`.

**EDIT:** after some (non rigorous) tests, it seems that the overhead introduced by `(locking this ...)` is similar to the one introduced by unnecessary reads from disk (note that I'm reading from a fast SSD, that might have already cached part of the data). Therefore, the best thread-safe solution for now (and for my specific hardware) would be to use a volatile cache.

```
(deftype DataSeq [id
                  ^long cnt
                  ^long i
                  ^{:unsynchronized-mutable true} cache]
  clojure.lang.IndexedSeq

  (index [_]    i)
  (count [_]    (- cnt i))
  (seq   [this] this)
  (more  [this] (if-let [s (.next this)] s '()))
  (next  [_]    (if (not= (inc i) cnt)
                  (DataSeq. id cnt (inc i) (next cache))))
  (first [_]
    (when-not (seq cache)
      (set! cache
            (with-open [f (open-data-file id)]
              ; open a memory mapped byte array on the file
              ; seek to the exact position to begin reading
              ; decide on an optimal amount of data to read
              ; eagerly read and return that amount of data
            )))
    (first cache)))
```

What still bothers me is that I must use mutable state just to stop `drop` (ie, "get out, you useless piece of data") from reading from the disk...